# What is the difference between CMF_NODEFAULT and CMF_DONOTPICKDEFAULT?

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-shell, windows-explorer, windows-shell-extension-menu

It seems to me like they do the same thing (tell [`QueryContextMenu`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-icontextmenu-querycontextmenu) to not call `SetMenuDefaultItem`).

For CMF_NODEFAULT, MSDN says "No item in the menu has been set as the default" which is a bit of a weird phrasing because the flag is a simple integer input parameter, it is not a pointer that can return a result you can check for. It goes on to say "A namespace extension should not set any of the menu items as the default". As a wild shot in the dark, this might perhaps be related to `DFM_MERGECONTEXTMENU`?

CMF_DONOTPICKDEFAULT which was added much later (Windows 7) all the documentation says is "When no verb is explicitly specified, do not use a default verb in its place". <s>This is also strange because `QueryContextMenu` does not know if there is an explicitly specified verb or not, `IContextMenu` is not informed about the verb until `InvokeCommand` is called and by that time, the desired verb is already set in `CMINVOKECOMMANDINFO`.</s> "verb explicitly specified" in context apparently means that the verbs `QueryContextMenu` knows about has an explicit default.

I don't see how it could be related to `ShellExecuteEx` and `SEE_MASK_INVOKEIDLIST`. If `ShellExecuteEx` is called without a verb, it wants `IContextMenu` to pick a default. If it is called with a verb, it is going to use that verb when calling `InvokeCommand` regardless of what the menu set as the default.

If I call `GetUIObjectOf` on the stock filesystem `IShellFolder`, the `IContextMenu` I get treats CMF_NODEFAULT and CMF_DONOTPICKDEFAULT the same, either of them being set causes `QueryContextMenu` to not call `SetMenuDefaultItem`.

Questions:

- What is the difference between the two flags and where does the difference matter?
- If I'm using `IContextMenu` to display a menu in my application, when (if ever) would these flags be useful?
- If I'm implementing `IContextMenu`, do I treat these flags differently in my `QueryContextMenu`?

Comment: I will work on improving the docs. `CMF_NODEFAULT` is a flag that tells the implementation of QueryContextMenu "Do not call SetMenuDefaultItem". `CMF_DONOTPICKDEFAULT` is a flag tells the implementation of QueryContextMenu, "If you are allowed to set the default (`CMF_NODEFAULT` not set), but you don't have an explicit default set, please don't choose an implicit default. Just leave the menu with no default." If you don't pass `DONOTPICKDEFAULT`, then the system implementation will choose the first registered verb as the implicit default, for backward compatibility.

Comment: @RaymondChen Could you clarify what "have an explicit default set" means? For example, if I set the default value in the shell key to the name of a verb sub key, DONOTPICKDEFAULT still stops it from becoming the default menu item.